# How to remove a branch?

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

Somehow I got a branch from other product source code. How can I remove it from  my repository?

[image]

Comment: Switch to another branch then `git branch -D <other_branch>`.

Comment: Are you asking specifically how to do this using Atlassian Sourcetree? If so, please clarify.

Answer (score 0):

#### Ensure you have master checked out

```
$ git checkout master
```

#### Safe delete the branch (recommended)

This will only delete the branch if all of its commits are in master

```
$ git branch -d branch-name
```

#### Force delete branch

This will delete the branch no matter what

```
$ git branch -D branch-name
```